# Parse Time String in Formula?

Tags: formula, validation-rule

[image]I have been trying to create formula which is '**Total_hours__c/9**', where Total_hours__c(Text Field), but its showing Error.
Formula Field name is '**Hours ratio'**

**i have to Split HH:MM format in formula feild 'Total hours'salesforce which is shown in images.**

for more ref please see in image[image]

Comment: Why are you dividing by 9? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: you are trying to divide some text by 9. math operations are available only with numbers

Comment: You're going to have to parse hours and minutes separately. You might also need to consider how it overflows to days, months, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Convert Text into number, Then divide the value by 9

```
 value(Total_hours__c)/9
```

Comment: I've tried this, its not working....

Comment: Can u add a screenshot ,where and what you have done ?

Comment: Also share what error your facing?

Comment: Hi Nitesh, in Above image mention #Error......i getting same..

Comment: are you facing any error while saving ?

Comment: formula has saved, but in feild its showing #Error.

Comment: Just create new record and tell me your still getting that #error

Comment: hi, Still i m getting Error...

Comment: hi, i uploded that formula box, check it and suggest me..

Comment: Formula is correct , there is no syntax error.. i have to know about   total_hours fields , your doing something wrong on that .

Comment: Total_Hours__c field is s text field which functionality working proper..